# Singleton vs Lock on Database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, synchronized

I have always used `Singleton` pattern creating apps with `SQLite`, but now I wonder if would it be best to use locks like this:

```
class DatabaseHelper {
    Object lock
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    // more properties....

    public void insert(BusinessEntity entity) {
         synchronized(lock) {
             db.insert(BusinessEntity.TABLE_NAME, // more params...
         }
    }

}
```

Since so far I have always used a singleton, I have never worried about a query not executing cause of multiple connection to the same DB, but as I understand, a lock would also solve this.

What is the better approach here and why?   And also, is that `synchronized` example all right? I've never used `synchronized` before so I'm not sure it is all right.

Comment: No android related. Please remove android tag.

Comment: I believe in Android better approach use custom `ConventProvider` as facade for SQLite, so framework can manually manage all lifecycles with this object inside application and you can also can have access from `Fragment` or `Activity`. Please see example [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html). Also it works perfect with [Loaders](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Singleton and Lock are 2 different concepts and are not interrelated. Lock acquire on object level but not on the class level. it does not matter that object is singleton object or normal object.

**Singleton**

In software engineering, the singleton pattern is a design pattern that restricts the instantiation of a class to one object. This is useful when exactly one object is needed to coordinate actions across the system. Please note singleton pattern will not apply lock on the object. For example 2 different threads are sharing the same single object reference and can call the different method on that single object simultaneously.

**Lock**

Lock means, we are restricting to access the same resource(object) by 2 different thread simultaneously. Java implemented the lock concept using the synchronized blocks or synchronized  method.

Note : in your code example you are acquiring lock on the "**lock**" object (i.e. synchronized(lock) )
but not on the "**db**" object. To acquire lock on the db object you will have to change the code to

```
synchronized(db){
......
}
```

Comment: Restricting the instantiation to just one instance, I avoid multiple connection to the same database, so what I really need is also lock calls on db object by synchronizing blocks, am I right?

Comment: (1) Restricting the instantiation to just one instance, I avoid multiple connection to the same database -> No, still 2 threads can share the reference of same object and can call its method simultaneously    |         
(2) Lock : if there are multiple threads in the your application which are accessing the database simultaneously and modifying it then only add the synchronized block or method. Since this is costly and add the overhead on the JVM.

Comment: One more question, I cannot make my `db` variable final, cause it is not initialized in the constructor. Should I synchronize the method instead of a block?

Comment: Since this is out of topic so please ask another question for this. also please explain what you want to make the final. you can use the  interface to create constant variable like dbname, path etc